# Binding HTML radio buttons with Spring controller,

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

Am developing this web app using Spring with a HTML view, filled with radio buttons, In each category, a user selects their option and finally submit their choices, How do I transfer or rather bind this values to the controller so that they are stored into a database. 
Am using thymleaf for rendering.

```
<form th:action=${/submit} >
<input type="radio" name="check1" value="a"/>
<input type="radio" name="check1" value="b"/>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" name="check2" value="c"/>
<input type="radio" name="check2" value="d"/>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" name="check3" value="e"/>
<input type="radio" name="check3" value="f"/>

<input type="button" value=submit />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm building with Thymeleaf too. Make controller method of this prototype.

My form

```
<form action="submit" method="post" >
<input type="radio" name="check1" value="a"/>
<input type="radio" name="check1" value="b"/>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" name="check2" value="c"/>
<input type="radio" name="check2" value="d"/>
<p></p>
<input type="radio" name="check3" value="e"/>
<input type="radio" name="check3" value="f"/>

<input type="submit" />
```

And controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "submit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView page(
        @RequestParam(name = "check1") String check1,
        @RequestParam(name = "check2") String check2,
        @RequestParam(name = "check3") String check3)
{
    return new ModelAndView("index").addAllObjects(createModel());
}
```

In the debugger i get next values :

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help man, but I had another question, since its a form, doesnt it need an entity class?

Comment: After you receive this values in your controller, call your service and create entity object, after save it throw DAO layer. If you want to show this after loading, make like this th:checked = ${value == 'a'}, add your value to the model. Form doesn't need an entity class, entity create with your architecture after receive in controller.